# Problem with authentication to external service - .NETAPP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iis

I have some problem with passing credeintals to my http get request.

Example of my code:

```
    private static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
    };

    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

    public static async Task<string> Connect(string url)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            // throw msg
        }
    }
```

The application is hosted by IIS server and what I understand we are passing to external service these credentials of user of that computer where the IIS server stand.

I would to use user windows credentials, not IIS server, how can I do that?

EDIT: I don't want to set 'super user' credentials on IIS server app pool.

Comment: The local and remote machines are in the same Domain and a Password Server is used to access the credentials.  When the HTTP connection is made the local user credentials are passed to the IIS and the IIS runs the application with the user credentials.  Do a Google Search for "msdn c# controller".

Comment: @jdweng ok, I understand, so this must be problem with IIS server configuration if it works fine for me on localhost. Have You any tips about configuration?

Comment: Are you getting a response?  What is the status code in the response?  Is it 200 OK or a 400/500 Error?  Look at the Microsoft Learn when doing a google search for "msdn c# controller credentials"

Comment: I received HTTP ERROR 500.

I'm using windows auth in my program.cs. I created roles depends on domain/group and I'm using it in controller.

Comment: Error 500 indicates that you made a connection to the server successfully and an exception occurred while the request was being processed.  IIS a client by default gets connected as a GUEST and has very little access to the server resources like the file system.  If you need to access files put them on a network drive (not on the IIS c:\ drive) where users have access to the files.

Comment: Hi Dzyzus, is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue?

Comment: @YurongDai nah, still in progress, if I will resolve it on my own I will add solution here:D